# Unable to play HLS playlist | video.js

Tags: wordpress, web, video.js, bandwidth, http-live-streaming

I'm working on WordPress site, and have programmatically integrated [Video.js](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) player in it. The screen is black and i can hear the audios. Most probably, it's due of bandwidth (as shown in screenshot attached).

Sometimes i'm able to watch videos, but most of the times, its black screen.

How to fix this issue. My code is as:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
    $var_value = $_GET['video_id'];
?>

<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" data-setup='{}'>
<source src="https://d3eykkkvwlu40v.cloudfront.net/v2/hls/<?php echo $var_value?>/<?php echo $var_value?>.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">

</video>

<script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?4.0.4"></script>
```

Please guide. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Check the bitrate of the playlists that don't work?

Comment: @aergistal, how to check that?

Comment: If the playlist is a master playlist it will contain `BANDWIDTH` tags. If it's a variant playlist use a tool like `ffmpeg` or download a segment and use `mediainfo`.

Comment: Maybe the playlist contains an audio-only playlist and the player switches to that as it's usual the lowest quality available?

Comment: @Daniel, yes we've an audio-only playlist entry in our m3U8 file. And it's the issue as player doesn't switch to anyother bandwidth if it picks up that audio playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Media Source Extension (MSE)](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/) in browsers don't support that you dynamically switch between an audio/video and an audio-only stream or vice versa. So if the player starts with the audio-only variant it won't be able to switch up at all or just plays the audio of that variant.

Theoretically it would be possible for a player to switch between those variants by re-initializing the MSE for every such switch. But I don't know if any player supporting this, for good reasons:

- the switch would not be completely seamless
- the buffered data would be deleted by the browser

This would be a bad user experience.

So I think there are three options: live with it, remove the audio-only variant or find/build a player that supports this. I'd go for the removal.

Comment: Thanks much @Daniel